# Using GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER BY in Ormlite returns wrong result

Tags: ormlite, android-sqlite

The following code gives an error

```
List<List<Consumption>> children = new ArrayList<List<Consumption>>();
try {
    for(DrinkType drinkType : groups){
        QueryBuilder<Consumption, ?> qb = getHelper()
                .getConsumptionDao().queryBuilder();
        qb.groupBy(Consumption.COLUMN_DRINK_ID).having("MIN("+Consumption.COLUMN_PRICE+")").orderBy(Consumption.COLUMN_PRICE, true);
        QueryBuilder<Drink, Integer> qb2 = getHelper().getDrinkDao().queryBuilder();
        qb2.where().eq(Drink.COLUMN_DRINKTYPE, drinkType.getFlag());
        qb.join(qb2);
        Log.d("Query", qb.prepareStatementString());
        children.add(qb.query());   
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems that the QueryBuilder puts the HAVING clause behind the ORDER BY clause instead of in front.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android query: 
SELECT `consumption`.* FROM `consumption` INNER JOIN `drink` ON
 `consumption`.`drink_id` = `drink`.`_id` WHERE `drink`.`drink_type` = 'P'
 GROUP BY `consumption`.`drink_id` ORDER BY `consumption`.`price` HAVING MIN(price)
```

I tried to work around this by doing a raw query instead, but if i use the following query

```
SELECT co.* FROM consumption co INNER JOIN drink dr ON dr._id = co.drink_id
 WHERE dr.drink_type = 'P' GROUP BY co.drink_id HAVING MIN(price) ORDER BY price
```

This gives back a different result than if i perform the same query directly on my sqlite database using SQLite Manager. I think ORMlite might have a problem when both HAVING and ORDER BY are used in the same query.

Is there a possible workaround so that I can get this query to work?

Comment: Is it generating a _bad_ query or can the ORDER be before _or_ after the HAVING?

Comment: It is indeed generating a bad query. It appears that the QueryBuilder generates a query where the ORDER is before the HAVING. It should be the other way around.